# AlamofireImage download into CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, alamofire

i want to cache image and few data from json to make persistent I know Alamofire Image has it own chade method, but i guess is only while app is alive when app close and open again chache is cleared so i have to download again image. so 
if my image are download like so

```
image.af_setImage(withURL: url)
```

it posible to save

```
imageEntity.save(image.image)
```

not sure to be exactly code but the idea is to save the image downloaded an set to image in CoreData.
and any idea behind the logic of this approach to cjeck if image exist in coreData and show from the if not download and save to coreData

Comment: I'm pretty sure that AF's image cache does not get cleared as you describe.

Comment: Better use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage it has more flexible caching options.

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is not designed to store ImageData or large data (files) but only String, Dates, integer... Just like a normal database.

If you want to save a data you could use AlamofireImageCache and save the image identifier in the CoreData Entity as a string. It's the most easy way to do it.

```
let imageCache = AutoPurgingImageCache(
    memoryCapacity: 100_000_000,
    preferredMemoryUsageAfterPurge: 60_000_000
)
imageCache.add(yourImage, withIdentifier: "YourImageIdentifier")
imageEntity.identifier = "YourImageIdentifier"
```

Then if you want to get your image you can do for example:

```
let cachedAvatar = imageCache.image(withIdentifier: imageEntity.identifier)
```

please check AlamofireImage documentation for more information about cache: https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

**Update**

If you want to make your own ImageCache on the hard-drive here you have an example of storing an Image:

```
func saveImage(image:UIImage){

     if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {

            let documentPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]!
            let filename = documentPath.appendingPathComponent("YourImageName")
            try? data.write(to: filename)
     }
}

func getImage(ForName name:String) -> UIImage?{ 
    let documentPath =    FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]!   
    let filename = documentPath.appendingPathComponent("YourImageName")         
     return UIImage(contentsOf:URL(fileURLWithPath: filename)) 
 }
```

Hope it helps !
Pierre

Comment: AutoPurgingImageCache is in-memory cache that means it purges all cached images when you exit the app

Comment: so how to make it persit form app exit

Comment: You can't make it working persistent. Try to use something like  SDWebImage it has more flexible cache which can be configured to work as in-memory or persistent https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.

Comment: I'am almost certain that alamofireCache store the image on the hard-drive and not  in memory.

Comment: yes it use an space in device-storage the question is if all that cache is removed after the app closed and if doesnt then if the app is offline it should return the cache image.

Comment: See my update, it should help you to make your own Cache.